# How to get a complete list of elements (including those which become visible on scrolling) in java appium?

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm using `appium` to automate testing in android using java. I want to get a list of `WebElements` but I am able to get a list of only those elements which are visible and not the ones which are reached on scrolling down.

This is what I am doing:

```
List <WebElement> resultListOfPrices = driver.findElements(By.id("some-id"));
```

How to get a complete list of elements (including those which become visible on scrolling)?

Comment: why dont you scroll to bottom and try findElements

Answer (score 0):

i think there is not particular way to get all list of elements but you can use following step to get all elements
1. get all elements which are currently displayed.
2. use swipe method once so next set of elements will be display.
3. then append new elements to your list.

i think it might help you to get achieve your goal.

thanks